# Como hacer para que un Id primary key que es autoincrementable inicie desde cero?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes amigos una pregunta sobre sql en particular phpmyadmin pasa que quiero que una tabla o bueno varias tablas sus ids primary key autoincrementable inicien desde cero, ya que he borrado todo desde cero pero al insertar datos me pone un nro mas al ultimo que habia , porque? si ya borre todo , como hago para que inicie desde cero porfa gracias.
[image: ejemplo]

por ejemplo si borro esa fila y vuelvo a insertar seguro que me inserta 15 y yo quiero q me inserte desde cero gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues bien, si leemos la [ayuda oficial de MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) sobre los AUTO_INCREMENT:

Vemos que la acción para reiniciar o establecer un nuevo valor de inicio al campo de una tabla es tan sencillo como:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

Donde `tblname` sera el nombre de nuestra tabla y `0` el numero por el que debe reiniciar (puede ser 0 o 50 o 1000, el que queramos).

Comment: Gracias. por responder amigo.